# Laptop display on TV, via usb to composite (RCA)

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors

I **was** using HDMI to display my laptop screen on a 32" TV, but now the HDMI port on the laptop is broken.

The 32" TV does not have SVGA *(for a usb-to-vga adapter)*, but it has composite (RCA) inputs. Is there such a thing as a usb-to-composite adapter/cable? When I google for `display laptop on composite monitor via usb`, I only get Amazon links for video capture devices. Would one of those work? Or am I out of luck --  or am I googling the wrong search string?

Comment: Have you looked into USB external graphic cards? As an alternative you also have many USB docks that have an HDMI output.

Comment: What type of USB do you have? Answers are highly dependant on that.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point - thanks for asking. Both laptops have 2 usb3 and 2 usb2 (Dell 15R 5521 and Dell m4800) - it is the m4800 that has the dead HDMI (the reason for this question).

Comment: Then get a usb3 to hdmi - as per David's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your laptop has USB 3 type A ports (usually a blue rectangle), you could get a `usb to hdmi adapter` that works like a (slow) external graphics card. (Make sure it says something about adding multiple displays, or including a graphics chip in the description and isn't just a USB C DisplayPort adapter.) This presumes the HDMI interface of the TV still works. It should be adequate for business use but probably not gaming.

Closer to your original suggestion, you could find a similar device that has a SVGA output instead of HDMI and then also buy a SVGA to composite video converter (I found one for about US$90), but the total cost would be greater and the analog video quality would presumably be less than using the digital HDMI connection.

From what I'm seeing, these external video adapters over USB all do require the bandwidth of USB 3 ports. I haven't found any with USB 2 connections.

You might also try to find out whether your laptop supports wireless video, sometimes known as Miracast. If it does, you could purchase a receiver for the TV that would output HDMI. I've found this to be a little laggy and less stable than a wired connection, no surprise, but again it should be fine for business-type use.

Comment: Composite only carries SD, about 560i or so, max. It's *possible* to do HDMI over USB 2, but it's sluggish compared to USB 3. Over USB-C, of course, you can run 8k ;)

Comment: Thanks for this info +1